# how to map linux lscpu command with windows cpu info

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, system, cpu

When running lscpu on rhel:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 4
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3000.000
BogoMIPS:              5985.27
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

and on windows it's look like this

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
```

i could find any thing from google which could map linux equilent to windows processor information.

I also followed this link: [lscpu](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/lscpu.1.html)

I am writing a script to get the cpu(s)/processor(s) information on widnows and linux as well. But I need to make sure, that for both fields are mapped properly.

Comment: You should use `wmic cpu` on windows Vista & above to determine CPU info.

Comment: When i use `wmic cpu` the output is VERY messy, to the point where it is unreadable

Comment: Readability improved: pipe wmic cpu > myfile .txt to a text file and view it with notepad

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an older question, but I wanted to expand on the existing comments since I was looking for a solution to this as well, and I found something after some digging.

Using `wmic cpu list /format:list` will provide a key value pair columnar list. Other formats like html table and csv are available. https://www.petri.com/command-line-wmi-part-3 provides a good overview of the formatting options and other `wmic` switches available

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Command Prompt, you can use Microsoft System Information on GUI.

Just open '**Run**' dialogue box using `win key+R` and then type `msinfo32` and press Enter.